# View "Automatic Maintenance" settings in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 8, you can change (and hence view) the "Automatic Maintenance" settings via the Action Center:

[image: See this image]

Now I don't really care about changing the settings, I just want to know at what time the "Automatic Maintenance" starts in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7 the "maintenance" tasks are all run via the Windows Task Scheduler and as such can be accessed from Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler. These are stored in the Task Scheduler library and have one task per maintenance task each with their own schedules.

Some examples of these tasks;

- Microsoft\Windows\Defrag
- Microsoft\Windows\DiskDiagnostic
- Microsoft\Windows\MemoryDiagnostic
- Microsoft\Windows\OfflineFiles
- Microsoft\Windows\SystemRestore

Comment: If you export one of these tasks, you can see how it has [`<MaintenanceSettings/>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskschedulerschema-maintenancesettings-maintenancesettingstype-element) ([see also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-maintenence)). The GUI doesn’t show this or make it easy to create this!